# Unity WebGL WebSocket Message Head

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine, websocket, unity-webgl

I have already made the multiplayer system. It is working fine. But I want to change message head ( or - tag, overhead etc...) to reducing data that transmitted.

Node.JS server side has the 'message' tag

```
wss.on('message',function incoming(message)){ 
...
...
}
```

But on Unity side i couldn't fine method or variable.

```
w = new WebSocket (new Uri (url));
yield return StartCoroutine (w.Connect());
w.SendString ("some_data");
```

How I can set the message tag. I know that socket.io can do that but I dont want to chance codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can use only 'message' tag in websocket. You can use tags inside of message. For example;

On Unity side ;

```
// add comma between event name and data
w.SendString (string.Format("{0},{1}",eventName,data);
```

On js side ;

```
wss.on('message',function incoming(message)){ 
    // find first comma
    var e = message.indexOf(",");
    if(e != -1){
        console.log("eventName : ",message.substring(0,e)," - data : ", message.substring(e+1,message.length));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But this will increase my data usage. Does socket.io chance the header ?

Comment: actually i didn't use socket.io but i guess it has tags.  if your concern is data usage, you can convert data to byte array and make first byte event id. this way you will add only one byte to data size and there will be 256 different event types.